# How to display HDR picture in Android?

Tags: java, android, colors, bitmap, hdr

I'm doing an android app to decompress, decode and display HDR pictures.
These HDR pictures use 2 bytes per component (A,R,G,B) so one pixel is represented by a 8 bytes value that can only fit with the long type.

I'm using android's Bitmap to display picture as they have a constructor allowing to do HDR by using [`Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#RGBA_F16):

```
int width = 1;
int height = 1;
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16);
```

Unfortunately I can't find any way to fill a pixel of the Bitmap. I use the recommended formula but it cannot be used in the setPixel(x,y,color) method of Bitmap because color has to be a int:

```
long color = (A & 0xffff) << 48 | (B & 0xffff) << 32 | (G & 0xffff) << 16 | (R & 0xffff);
image.setPixel(0,0,color); //Argument type error
```

.
I have also tried with Color ([which has a HDR compatible method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#color-longs)), Paint and Canvas but no Bitmap method accepts them to set only one pixel.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're doing image editing, you shouldn't use setPixel anyway.  Get the bytes of the image and edit the image directly.  Repeated calls to setPixel is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your answer but it doesn't help me. My main problem is displaying a 8bytes per pixel picture in Android (if possible with Bitmap). Do you know any way to display HDR content (like a .hdr file or a bytestream) on Android ?

Comment: The entire architecture on Android is for ARGB, with support for smaller formats (565, grayscale, etc).  You're going to have to downscale.   Which is what I bet that constructor you found is doing.  But if it makes you feel any better it would have to happen at some point anyway-  the hardware isnt going to support 16 bit output per channel on the screen.

Comment: Then I have trouble understanding why HDR10 video (10bits per component) is supported by Android on my Galaxy Note 8 but not HDR pictures.
The android documentation is really unclear about this unfortunately...

Comment: Completely different subsystems.  Video uses OpenGL to directly write the video buffers.  Not really comparable.You may be able to use openGL directly so long as you do everything via a custom view or SurfaceView, but I'm not sure its worth the effort.  Either way you wouldn't be using a Bitmap object most likely.

Comment: Well I think that I will have to get my hands dirty with OpenGL then.  
Thanks for your time and answers, you cleared a big misunderstanding I had!

Comment: @Nicolas have you found the sollution. I am facing the same problem - I have only found info how to displayer hdr video content on android: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/hdr

Comment: I have found also this little information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config

Comment: @Nicolas Did you  tried using glide or Picasso image loader instead yourself your decompressing image?

Comment: @404pio unfortunately we haven't found any solution :(  As an alternative we ended up using tone mapping to reduce the pixel space to a basic 8 bits per component (using opencv tonemappers).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to open an HDR file, such as 16-bit png, and then display it, you can use ImageDecoder.setTargetColorSpace to create bitmap with format `Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16` like so:

```java
File file = new File(...);
ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(file);
Drawable drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source, (decoder, info, src) -> {
    decoder.setTargetColorSpace(ColorSpace.Named.EXTENDED_SRGB);
});
```

If you need to display HDR image that is stored in memory you can use `Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer`, as this method allows to set pixels of the bitmap without conversion of color space the way `Bitmap.setPixel` does. In this case you need to pack 4 channels represented by [`Half`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Half) values into long for each pixel, then write these long values into a [`Buffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer) and finally copy pixels from the buffer to the bitmap.

```java
LongBuffer buffer = LongBuffer.allocate(width * height);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        // fill pixels values as needed
        float r = (float)y / height;
        float g = (float)y / height;
        float b = (float)y / height;
        float a = 1f;
        long rBits = Half.halfToShortBits(Half.toHalf(r));
        long gBits = Half.halfToShortBits(Half.toHalf(g));
        long bBits = Half.halfToShortBits(Half.toHalf(b));
        long aBits = Half.halfToShortBits(Half.toHalf(a));
        long color = aBits << 48 | bBits << 32 | gBits << 16 | rBits;
        buffer.put(color);
    }
}
buffer.rewind();

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```